# Slide navbar from left using pure css

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making angular application where i am using bootstrap 4 navbar **without jquery or any third party plugin**..

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-theme">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="toggleNavigation()" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-light">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/template" href="#">Template</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/product" href="#">Product</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
          <!-- I have implemented the duplicate of above give navbar-nav for responsive.. Is there any need for this or can we do with the above code itself?? -->
      <div *ngIf="showResponsivenavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-light bg-custom-light p-3">
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/template" href="#">Template</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/product" href="#">Product</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
```

**Css**:

```
.bg-custom-light a {
  color: #fff!important;
}
.bg-custom-light {
    background-color: #e51631;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:7%;
    left:0;
    width:150px;
    -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
```

I would like to make navbar toggle on responsive screen on click the icon bars which displays the navbar at bottom of icon bars.
The navbar gets displayed but i would like add the transition effect as it needs to slide in from left with certain duration, so i have given the following in css,

```
    -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
```

But i couldn't see any animation effect in it. Kindly help me to achieve the slide in animation effect from left while clicking the toggle icon bar.. I also searched for the solutions around but couldn't get the right one and tried with transition css that too not helped me.

Working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmwnxt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transition needs to know both the before state, and the after state for it to work. Also, if the element is removed from the DOM with `*ngIf`, it won't exist for us to animate it.

Instead, you can add a class to it that specifies whether it's open or not

```
 [ngClass]="{'open': showResponsivenavbar}"
```

Then, change the CSS so that, be default, it's off the screen. When we add the `open` class, we can then move it on-screen, like so:

```
  .navbar-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:7%;
    left: -150px;
    width:150px;
    -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
  }

  .open .navbar-nav {
    left: 0;
  }
```

Now, when the `open` class is added, the menu will transition from being `left: -150px` to `left: 0`

**[Here is a fork of your Stackblitz to show it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyex4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

Comment: For a better transition you could use `transform` instead of `left`. Because it then get's its own render layer. Setting `left: 0;` and `transform: translateX( -200px );` as default

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. Can you clarify me another thing in the code i have posted?? I have duplicated the ```navbar-nav``` separately for responsive.. As because i am not using jquery i need to give custom function so using boolean, i am opening the ```showResponsivenavbar``` which is the duplicate of previous.. You could able to see this in code.. Is this is the only way or we can open the navbar with the same code without duplicating?? Just i am asking an extra suggestion in this question as you are expert in angular..

Comment: @ManiRaj Im not sure what you mean, without duplicating what?

Comment: @user184994, You can see in my code ```            <ul class="navbar-nav text-light bg-custom-light p-3">
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/template" href="#">Template</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pb-2">
                    <a routerLink="/product" href="#">Product</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
 ```

Comment: The above code was repeated two times.. Why because i am making duplication for responsive separately (which has that  ```[ngClass]="{'open': showResponsivenavbar}"```.. The solution which you gave is also in that duplication only.. If you go through my code completly then you will get to know that duplication is required or in that first ```navbar``` itself we can do it??

Comment: As far as I can tell, you shiould be able to remove the top one. I've commented it out on that StackBlitz to show you want I meant.

Comment: @user184994, I could able to see the commented code.. But what will happen to that menu when it is in larger screen (not responsive)... Its empty now in larger screens...

Comment: @user184994, I am once again saying you this is not related to the question i ahave asked but as you are expert i am asking is it right approach?? To be litlle bit clear, in bootstrap if we use jquery then on toggle icon the dropdown will come and vice versa will happen on another click And also in larger screens the same navbar will be split out.. (No need of separate and the single thing will take care of all devices)... But here we are customising and hence is it possible to handle it in single??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with bootstrap to be able to answer that